# how to physically remove untagged docker images

Tags: docker

when I run a command such as sudo docker rmi me/myimage  I get the responce    ...image untagged,   but, when I rerun sudo docker images I can see that this "untagged" image is still there, and, if I run df -h   I can see that the actual files still exist and occupy the file system space.
What command or procedure can I use to physically remove the unneeded images?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should be able to remove untagged Docker images using the `"dangling=true"` flag:

```
sudo docker rmi $(sudo docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

source:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/

Comment: I still keep seeing things like this:    <none>                       <none>              5e76bce9b555        2 days ago          3.488 GB
<none>                       <none>              f4ef5d62dac0        2 days ago          3.348 GB
<none>                       <none>              1fb11b87d78e        2 days ago          2.707 GB
<none>                       <none>              9f4c46af8113        2 days ago          386.9 MB
<none>                       <none>              22fcde4c8949        2 days ago          16.45 MB
<none>                       <none>              c7b84131dd95

Comment: Can you be a bit more specifc? what do you mean by "keep seeing"? It would be best if you added specific commands you are running and the output to your question via an edit. Best to be very explicit as to the commands you've run and in what order.

Comment: when I run sudo docker images     I see a number of entries like:            <none>                       <none>              9f4c46af8113        2 days ago          386.9 MB

Answer (score 21):

First you need to remove exited containers, then remove dangling images.

```
docker rm $(docker ps -q -f status=exited)
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)
```

After all, I created the below script as ~/bin/dclean and have been using it.

```
#!/bin/sh

processes=$(docker ps -q -f status=exited)
if [ -n "$processes" ]; then
  docker rm $processes
fi

images=$(docker images -q -f dangling=true)
if [ -n "$images" ]; then
  docker rmi $images
fi
```

Comment: nice, it is more complete. Removing exited container shall be first step to keep it clean

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This command will remove all the dangling images and containers from docker.

```
docker system prune -f
```

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer since api v 1.25, see docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/

Answer (score 1):

If John Petrone solution doesn't work, try removing those images referring explicitly the `IMAGE ID` you see when you run `docker images`. You can remove all of them with one command

`for i in`sudo docker images | grep \ | awk '{print $3}'`; do sudo docker rmi $i; done`

PD: I don't know John Petrone answer. It works nicely with Docker 1.4.1

Answer (score 0):

you can delete single  images by their image id...

```
docker images
docker rmi <image-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

This commands also work

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep "^<none>" | awk '{print $3}')
```

Delete images with force to forgo stopped containers that might be using image

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images | grep "^<none>" | awk '{print $3}')
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i have removed the untagged image by the
below command

```
        # find untagged images 
        IMAGE_IDS=$(sudo docker images | grep "^<none>" | awk '{print $"3"}')
        # in case of no untagged images found do nothing
        if [ -n "$IMAGE_IDS" ]; then
                sudo docker rmi $IMAGE_IDS > /dev/null 2>&1
        fi
```