# Remove existing image when using `docker commit`?

Tags: docker

I have a script which I use to build docker images. The script starts up a docker container, executes some commands on it, and then does `docker commit` to fixturize the image. When I commit with an image name/tag, and then later commit with the *same* image name/tag, I would like the previous image to be removed, since at that point it's just taking up disk space. Instead it sticks around (I can see it in `docker images`, with its repository and tag both listed as `<none>`). Is there a way to have docker automatically remove these replaced images?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to physically remove untagged docker images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377446/how-to-physically-remove-untagged-docker-images)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not automtaically, but Docker does know which layers are not used in images, and you can remove those "dangling" image layers like this:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

While you're clearing up, you can also remove exited containers:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

And dangling volumes:

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```